# How to update select input inside renderIU?

Tags: r, shiny

I show you my shiny application, but I have a problem, I cannot update the selectimput, I have used updateSelectInput but it does not work.
I have two selectInputs inside a tabsetPanel, since I need to update the table with two filters, one is the category and the other the subcategory.
here my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)


cat1<-rep("LINEA BLANCA", 75)
cat2<- rep("VIDEO", 75)
subcat1<-rep("LAVADORAS", 40)
subcat2<- rep("REFRIS", 35)
subcat3<- rep("TV", 40)
subcat4<- rep("SONIDO", 35)
vent<-sample(100:900, 150, replace=T)
segm1<-rep("AAA", 25)
segm2<-rep("BBB", 25)
segm3<-rep("CCC", 25)
segm4<-rep("ABB", 25)
segm5<-rep("ACC", 25)
segm6<-rep("BAC", 25)
db<- tibble(segment=c(segm1,segm2,segm3,segm4,segm5,
                      segm1),CATEGORIA=c(cat1,cat2), SUBCAT=c(subcat1,subcat2, subcat3, subcat4), vent=vent)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title
  titlePanel("EXAMPLE"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  
                  tabPanel("Ana_inv", uiOutput("selectcat"), uiOutput("selectsubcat"),DT::dataTableOutput("ana_inv")),
                  #tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                  tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
      )
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$selectcat <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Cat", "Seleccione Categoria", choices = c("ALL",as.vector(db$CATEGORIA)))
  })
  output$selectsubcat <- renderUI({
    #opciones<- db_prueba %>% filter(CATEGORIA==input$CAT)
    selectInput("Subcat", "Seleccione Subcategoria", choices = c("ALL",as.vector(db$SUBCAT)))
  })
  
  activar<- reactive({
    
    req(input$Cat)
    req(input$Subcat)

    opciones<- db %>% filter(CATEGORIA==input$Cat)
    if(input$Cat == "TODOS") {
      
      filt1 <- quote(CATEGORIA != "@?><")
      
      
    } else {
      
      filt1 <- quote(CATEGORIA == input$Cat) 
      
    }
    
    
    if (input$Subcat == "TODOS") {
      
      filt2 <- quote(SUBCAT != "@?><")
      
      
    } else {
      
      filt2 <- quote(SUBCAT == input$Subcat)
      
    }
    
    db %>%
      filter_(filt1) %>%
      filter_(filt2) %>% group_by(segment)%>%
      summarise(SKUs=n(), 
                vta=sum(vent))
    
  })
  # Return the formula text for printing as a caption ----
  output$ana_inv <- DT::renderDataTable({
    activar()
    
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So I need that if the category "LINEA BLANCA" is selected in the subcategory it only shows "REFRIS" and "LAVADORAS", but also if someone selects "ALL" in the category he can also select each subcategory, that is, it can be filtered by subcategory assuming I only want to see subcategories.

I have tried many ways but none works, any ideas? you can run the application in R to get an idea of what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$selectcat <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Cat", "Seleccione Categoria", choices = c("ALL",as.vector(db$CATEGORIA)))
  })
  output$selectsubcat <- renderUI({
    req(input$Cat)
    if (input$Cat=="ALL"){ df <- db
    }else df <- db %>% filter(CATEGORIA %in% input$Cat)
    selectInput("Subcat", "Seleccione Subcategoria", choices = c("ALL",as.vector(df$SUBCAT)))
  })
  
  activar<- reactive({
    
    req(input$Cat,input$Subcat)
    
    if (input$Cat=="ALL"){ df <- db
    }else df <- db %>% filter(CATEGORIA %in% input$Cat)
    
    if (input$Subcat=="ALL"){ df <- df
    }else df <- df %>% filter(SUBCAT == input$Subcat)

    df %>%
      group_by(segment) %>%
      summarise(SKUs=n(), 
                vta=sum(vent))
    
  })
  # Return the formula text for printing as a caption ----
  output$ana_inv <- DT::renderDataTable({
    activar()
  })
  
}
```